# Can I extend conditional expression in C++

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

Can I make conditional expression with more than one else if:

Casual condition:

```
int number = 50;
if (number > 23) cout << "The variable number is greater then 23 " << endl;
else cout << "23 is greater then variable number"  << endl;
```

Conditional expression:

```
 int number = 50;
 cout << (number > 23 ? "The variable number is greater then 23 " : "23 is greater then variable number")<< endl;
```

Is it possible to add more "else if" in this second case or it's only possible to add one condition consisting from "if and else"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to an `else if`, you could just have the else case be another conditional:

```cpp
condition1 ? val1 :
condition2 ? val2 :
condition3 ? val3 :
val4
```

which is kind of equivalent to

```cpp
if (condition1)
    val1
else if (condition2)
    val2
else if (condition3)
    val3
else
    val4
```

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way to have an else-if in an inline conditional ('?:' syntax). You could maybe approach this with nested '?:s' <s>with parentheses</s>, but it'd be ugly.

Edit: looking at the other answer, i guess you can and it's not that ugly! But I haven't seen this pattern in practice.

Comment: _"But I haven't seen this pattern in practice."_ Probably you will. I've seen it often in different companies and different projects.

Comment: That's probably fair then. I've mainly worked in Java, where I think parentheses would be necessary for this pattern, in which case I think my answer stands! But the question was about C++ and I've only worked on one major C++ project.